# Is it possible to have a UITextField selected without a keyboard present?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, keyboard, uitextfield

### Summary of my situation

My app uses a barcode scanner that acts as an external keyboard. While on a particular view I want to have a hidden textfield selected without having any keyboard present. Then I can have the barcode scanner send data to this textfield.

I am using an IPad Air 2.

### What I have done so far

I have set the text fields inputView and inputAccessoryView to empty UIViews.

```
_barcodeText.inputView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
_barcodeText.inputAccessoryView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

This mostly works, however it leaves this top part of the keyboard:
[image]

I have tried solving this by removing the UIRemoteKeyboardWindow within the textfields delegate methods, but this solution seems to be very inconsistent and might be causing more problems in other parts of my app. The code I'm using to do this is as follows:

```
// LOOP THROUGH WINDOWS
for(NSObject *window in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]){
        
    // GET CLASS NAME
    NSString *name = NSStringFromClass([window class]);
        
    // CHECK FOR KEYBOARD WINDOW
    if([name isEqualToString:@"UIRemoteKeyboardWindow"]){
            
        // REMOVE KEYBOARD
        [(UIWindow*)window removeFromSuperview];
        [(UIWindow*)window setHidden:true];
            
    }
        
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot fully get rid of the keyboard. What I have done is used Sockets barcode scanner, Linked here : https://www.socketmobile.com/home/?languageRedirect=true

They have an SDK that sends data through bluetooth and the keyboard is left alone to do whatever you want with it.

Answer (score 1):

If your hidden `UITextField` will never actually require user input, just make it a hidden `UILabel` instead, or just store the data in a `String` variable rather than in any UI object at all.

Comment: The problem with that is I need the data to be read in by a barcode scanner, and the barcode scanner acts as an external keyboard. I can't write data onto a label in that way

Answer (score 0):

in `UIViewController viewDidLoad()` set keyboard observer:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(keyboardShow),
                                           name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)

    func keyboardShow(){
    for w in UIApplication.shared.windows {
        let x = NSStringFromClass(w.classForCoder)
            if x == "UIRemoteKeyboardWindow" {
                w.frame.origin.x = -500
                // OR 
               w.frame = CGRect.zero
            }
    }
}
```

The code above will hide the keyboard outside main window bounds...

Hope this helps

Comment: I don't think I'm able to manipulate the frame of a UIWindow. I tried removing the UIRemoteKeyboardWindow in the UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, but nothing happend. I was however able to remove it in the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification after it appeared for a split second. Is there no better way of doing this?

Comment: removing UIRemoteKeyboardWindow is dangierus because this approach breaks UITextField life cycle .... i tried my code on iPhone 5S and keyboard doesn't show any more and  using UIKeyboardWillShowNotification moved  it aside before it appeared... not sure if you tried it and on what device ..

Comment: I was able to modify the frame and the keyboard no longer is showing, however its created a bunch of constraints in the keyboard that break. Should I be worried about these broken constraints?